# Export .xlsx file, PHP

Tags: php, excel, download, header, xlsx

I saw similar questions, but could not find the solution. I need to download existed .xlsx file. Downloading is OK and file is opening with LibreofficeCalc but MS EXCEL returns me "We found a problem with some content in ..." after recover all is good. On the other hand, if I downloading file from server without browser, Excel opens it with no errors.
Download code:

```
if ($fileSize) {
            while (@ob_end_clean()) ;
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sms_report_'.$f);
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            header('Content-Length: '.$fileSize);
            flush();
            readfile($fileName);
        } else {...
```

Comment: What does `$fileName` contain? Some people send CSV, HTML or some other random formats, declare it as Excel and call it a day, but that doesn't make it Excel.

Comment: $fileName  contains string with path and filename $fileName = '/var/lib/../'.$f; as I mentioned all is working with Libreoffice but not with MS. Also I found that file size after downloading is higher than original file

Comment: Alright, I'll rephrase my comment. What does the file on disk that `$fileName` points to contain? If Excel doesn't think it's valid Excel perhaps it has a point, no matter how good is LibreOffice reading your mind.

Comment: Yes it is "true" .xlsx file created by python openpyxl. also on downloading the file from the server not though browser, there is no the issue.

Comment: Thanx everyone for help, I've solve the issue. I've checked .xlsx file with text editor and got {"rid":"5f04583c5e6d0","ret":null,"success":true} at the end of file. that was causing the issue. this json came from buffer. Solution:   ... header('Content-Length: '.$fileSize);
   flush();
   readfile($fileName);
   exit;
  } else {...   added "Exit" after readfile()